# Are the lightning component are used for salesforce1 or we can us it as both side as mobile and web app

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Are the lightning component are used for salesforce1 or we can us it as both side as mobile and web app. can anyone give me a guides on this. right now I developed lightning app which works on mobile not on web app. I need to get the same thing on web.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the app by https://xxx.lightning.force.com/c/yourapp.app .
Or you can load the app on a Visualforce page within an iframe:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:iframe src="/c/yourappname.app"/>
</apex:page>
```

[image]